# WebJobsStartup in Azure Functions v2 not working when targeting netcoreapp2.1

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function v2 app, that I originally targeted `netcoreapp2.1`.

I then have a `Startup.cs` class, annotated with `[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]` to set up [dependency injection](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/dependency-injection-for-azure-functions/), but it did not register `Startup` in the `extensions.json` file.

This is happening during `build`. [Publish has another issue at the moment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3386#issuecomment-419565714).

When I change the `TargetFramework` in the project file to `netstandard2.0` it successfully adds `Startup` to `extensions.json`:

```
{
  "extensions":[
    { "name": "AzureStorage", "typeName":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.AzureStorageWebJobsStartup, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"},
    { "name": "Startup", "typeName":"MyApp.Functions.Startup, MyApp.Functions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
  ]
}
```

While I do not have exact reasons to target `netcoreapp2.1`, I am curious to figure out why it doesn't work, as v2 was [changed to target .Net Core by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010420/azure-functions-v2-changed-from-net-standard-to-net-core).

Comment: check this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3386#issuecomment-419565714. The actual workaround is to have a `Directory.Build.targets` file in the project folder. I've encounter the same issue earlier this week

Comment: As far as I know, this is the case when you `publish`. I see the same happening on build when I target `netcoreapp2.1`. The targets file copies the `extensions.json` file produced by `build` into the `publish` folder - but I'm getting a wrong one created in build.

Comment: Any ideas so far ?

Comment: @SashaFentsyk Target `netstandard2.0` instead.

Comment: Did you manage to find any more info on this, or is there a bug open we can track do you know?

Comment: @tank104 I didn't find more info - I got it working by changing the `TargetFramework` to `netstandard2.0`, so I never looked back...

Comment: Do you know where best to log a bug for this so it can get fixed? I am happy to do it, just not sure the right place?

Comment: This looks fixed now in Microsoft.NET.SDK.Functions as of 1.0.25

Answer (score 7):

I have upgraded the Microsoft.NET.SDK.Functions to version 1.0.26 from manage nuget packages and it worked.

[image]

Comment: Please add the "how to upgrade to 1.0.26"

Comment: Go to manage nuget packages and go to updates tab and you can update

Answer (score 0):

This looks fixed now just upgrade Microsoft.NET.SDK.Functions to version 1.0.25 +

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had simply missed to explicitly set `host.json` to be copied. Adding these rows to the `csproj` file did the works:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```